# Why does Matlab remove dots on a (polar) plot when saving as an image?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, save, export

I construct a plot in Matlab, for example

```
plot([1 2 3],[1 0 -1],'b.-')
```

[image]

If I save this figure as a .png/.jpg/.tif file (using `File`-`Save as...`), Matlab removes the dots and plots only the lines:

[image]

Why is this? How can I save the figure as it is? [Matlab 2012b]

**Edit**
In the case of a `plot`, this can be done by

```
plot([1 2 3],[1 0 -1],'b.-','MarkerSize',10)
```

as suggested by Suever.
Now I want to apply this to a `polar`

```
h=polar(t,r);
set(h,'MarkerSize',100)
```

but this does not change the `MarkerSize`.

Comment: Did you try increasing the `MarkerSize` of the dots?

Comment: I suggest using `export_fig` to save images.

Comment: @Suever I did not know this quick option. I made the `plot` MWE but I want to apply it to a `polar`. How can I access `MarkerSize` there? `polar(t,r,'MarkerSize',10)` gives `Error: Too many input arguments`.

Comment: @Karlo Get the line object and increase the `MarkerSize`: `plt = polar(t, r); set(plt, 'MarkerSize', 20)`

Comment: @Suever This does not change the `MarkerSize`. I edited the question.

Comment: If you want to use `MarkerSize` you have to use `polarplot` not `polar`